# Difficulty using scipy.integrate.odeint to solve radial wave function of hydrogen

Tags: python, scipy, physics, odeint

I'm trying to use scipy.integrate.odeint to solve for the wavefunction of an atom of hydrogen, but it doesn't seem to give the correct form of solution. Here is the function that should be implementing the SE equation.

```
def eq(y,r,l,E_nl):  
[u_nl, v_nl] = y

#constants
alpha = 1/137 #Fine structure constant 
mu = 5.11E-1 #MeV/c^2 
V = -alpha/r #Potential  


dydr = [v_nl, (l*(l+1)/r**2 - 2 * mu * (E_nl - V))*u_nl]
return dydr
```

And here is the code that supposedly implements the solver

```
ode(eq,y0,r,args=(l,E_nl))
```

The constants are all in natural units.

```
y0 = [0, 1], l = 1, E_nl = 13.6e-6, r = np.linspace(1,7000,10000)
```

I have looked at many different implementations of odeint and cant figure out why my code isn't producing the correct solution. [Wavefunction produced by the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AKgw.png)

Comment: It would help to have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could simply copy and run to reproduce your result.   In the current version of the code, you haven't defined the parameters `l`, `E_nl`, `y0` or `r` that you pass to the solver.  Also, you say "I'm trying to use scipy.integrate.odeint" but the code you wrote is `ode(eq,y0,r,args=(l,E_nl))`; presumably that should be `odeint(...)`.

Comment: Sorry, i've edited the question to include the variables

Comment: Aren't you missing a term involving `v_nl` in the equation for `d(v_nl)/dr` (second element in `dydr`)?  Something like `-(2/r)*v_nl`.

Comment: I dont think so, I'm fairly certain the equation is written properly. There is only one derivative in the equation and its the second derivative of u_nl or simply the first derivative of v_nl

Comment: The differential equation for the radial wavefunction shown [here](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node232.html) includes the term (2/r)*d(R_El)/dr.  Is that not the same equation that you are solving?

Comment: Do you have a source for how to write it as a system of first order ODEs? It's very hard to reconstruct from code.

Comment: Apologies, I have found the solution, the energy for the l=1 state is not -13.6eV so that was the source of the issue.